# ¿Cómo generar una clausula para una función de agregación SUM()?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Me pasa que tengo que realizar un ejercicio en el cual debo generar dos columnas basadas en una función de agregación (sum) y cada una es según un código que comparten en común esta tabla y otra en la cual sólo hay dos registros (1 que correspondería a "Abono" y 2 a "Rescates")

```
SELECT
      UPPER(TO_CHAR(CLI.NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || CLI.DVRUN) AS "RUN CLIENTE",
      INITCAP(CLI.PNOMBRE || ' ' || CLI.SNOMBRE || ' ' || CLI.APPATERNO || ' ' || CLI.APMATERNO) AS "NOMBRE CLIENTE",
      SUM(MO.MONTO_MOVIMIENTO) AS "ABONOS",
      SUM(MO.MONTO_MOVIMIENTO) AS "RESCATES"
FROM
      CLIENTE CLI JOIN MOVIMIENTO MO
      ON (CLI.NRO_CLIENTE = MO.NRO_CLIENTE)
GROUP BY
      CLI.NUMRUN,
      CLI.DVRUN,
      CLI.PNOMBRE,
      CLI.SNOMBRE,
      CLI.APPATERNO,
      CLI.APMATERNO;
```

Lo que busco realizar es colocar una clausula WHERE para "ABONOS" Y "RESCATES" donde una sume sólo las del código X mientras que la otra sólo las del código Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te serviría usar el `case...when`:

```sql
select upper(to_char(cli.numrun, '09G999G999')
             || '-'
             || cli.dvrun)       as "RUN CLIENTE",
       initcap(cli.pnombre
               || ' '
               || cli.snombre
               || ' '
               || cli.appaterno
               || ' '
               || cli.apmaterno) as "NOMBRE CLIENTE",
       sum(case
             when tucodigo = 'x' then mo.monto_movimiento
             else 0
           end)                  as "ABONOS",
       sum(case
             when tucodigo = 'y' then mo.monto_movimiento
             else 0
           end)                  as "RESCATES"
from   cliente cli
       join movimiento mo
         on ( cli.nro_cliente = mo.nro_cliente )
group  by cli.numrun,
          cli.dvrun,
          cli.pnombre,
          cli.snombre,
          cli.appaterno,
          cli.apmaterno;
```

Comment: Esta forma me sirvió perfectamente, se me ocurrió en algún momento el case pero no me resultó, gracias por tu query, un saludo!